# Hitting a roadblock while solving a logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^{ 5-\log _{ 3 }{ x }  }=9x^2$$

Steps I took:

$$\log _{ 3 }{ x^{ 5-\log _{ 3 }{ x }  } } =\log _{ 3 }{ 9x^{ 2 } } $$

$$(5-\log _{ 3 }{ x } )(\log _{ 3 }{ x) } =\log _{ 3 }{ 9x^{ 2 } } $$

$$5\log _{ 3 }{ x } -(\log _{ 3 }{ x } )^{ 2 }=\log _{ 3 }{ 9x^{ 2 } } $$

$$(\log _{ 3 }{ x } )^{ 2 }-5\log _{ 3 }{ x } =-\log _{ 3 }{ 9x^{ 2 } } $$

I am trying to turn this into a quadratic equation to then solve with substitution, but I can't seem to manipulate the right hand side of this equation in any way that will allow me to do this.

Hints are much better appreciated than the actual answer.

Comment: $-\log_3 9x^2=-\log_3 9 - \log_3 x^2=-2-\log_3 x^2=-2-2\log_3 x$. Last equality holds because we know $x>0$.

Comment: we know $x>0$ because the term $\log_3 x$ occurs in the first line of the Q

Comment: @user236182 Feel free to add that comment as an actual answer. I'll accept it and +1

Answer (score 0):

Something to try:

Convert your right side to
$$-\log _{ 3 }{ 9x^{ 2 } }=-\log _{ 3 }{( 3x)^{ 2 } }=-2\log_{3}{(3x)}$$

Then you convert your left-side terms to $$\log_{3}{(3x)}$$ instead of $$\log_{3}{(x)}$$

See where that takes you.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
x^{ 5-\log _{ 3 }x }&=9x^2
\\x^{3-\log_{3}x}&=9\qquad\text{as $x\neq0$}
\\&=x^{\log_x 9}
\\&=x^{2\log_x 3}
\\&=x^{\frac 2{\log_3 x}}
\\3-u&=\frac 2u\qquad\text{(putting $u=\log_3x$)}
\\u^2-3u+2&=0
\\(u-2)(u-1)&=0
\\u=\log_3x&=1,2
\\x&=3,9
\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$